# NullReferenceException when using "not StartWith" in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove all elements that have attribute value that doesn't start with specific text

Thanks to Jon Skeet I got the first part however some elements doesn't contain this attribute, therefore I got `NullReferenceExpection` with the message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I added an extra check for null value but it still doesn't work any idea?

```
elements =(from el in xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName)
where ( !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value)
&& !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartsWith(searchBeforeStar))
select el);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test if your node contains the attribute before testing it.

Add `el.Attribute(attributeName) != null` :

```
elements =(from el in xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName) 
           where ( el.Attribute(attributeName) != null
                && !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) 
                && !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartsWith(searchBeforeStar))
           select el);
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `Equals` on a `null` attribute triggers the exception. It is not necessary (and in fact, it is incorrect) to compare `XAttribute`'s value to `DBNull`, because LINQ2XML uses "plain" `null` for missing attributes.

Try this:

```
elements =(from el in xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName) where (
    el.Attribute(attributeName) != null &&
    el.Attribute(attributeName).Value != null && 
    !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartsWith(searchBeforeStar)
)select el);
```